# Fastest way to find index of elements in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a set of samples (say X) with some features (say Y) on which I need to run some machine learning algorithms (say PCA). One way is to generate the matrix (sample, feature). My approach to constructing the matrix involves 2 steps:

1. Get all the feature values for the entire dataset. Let's call it a pool.
2. For a sample, for each value in the sample, find the value's index in the pool. The index's where the value is present is 1 and absent is 0.

Ex: Consider the below example

```
sample1 = A, B, D
sample2 = A, C, E
sample3 = A, C, D
```

1. Generated pool = A, B, C, D, E
2. Generated matrix

   - sample 1 => 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
   - sample 2 => 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
   - sample 3 => 1, 0, 0, 1, 0

The challenge in generating this matrix is that, the data is very huge. The number of rows are **465337** and the number of columns are **35526155**.

Generating the pool took around 20 minutes and even though this is slow, I am fine with it. But when generating the vector (i.e. row) of the matrix, I have to get for all the values of the sample under consideration the index of that value in the pool.

This is taking a huge time. Is there a better approach to find the index of elements? If the procedure itself is not optimal, please let me know of a better way to generate the matrix.

Also, I am just storing the indices and constructing a CSR matrix out of it instead of a dense matrix.

Comment: What *exactly* are you working with? what are the samples? tuples? How are you generating the pool? 20 minutes seems like along time, how many samples, and how are you doing it? The problem is that you are probably using some sequence type, an array or list, and you should be using a `dict` of sorts to do this.

Comment: Consider it analogous to this, each sample is a document and the feature is each word. So the pool is all the unique words present in all the documents. 
To generate the pool, I am iterating through each document and adding each word to a set. Going through 0.4M documents and generating the pool took that long (20 minutes).
I don't know how dict would work here ? Can you give some small example ?

Comment: No, we don't need an *analogy*, we need *specifics*. What do you mean by "document"? A string? So you are iterating over a ... list of words formed from tokenizing a string? Or what? And You say you are adding those documents to  *set*, but then you say you *index* the pool, but `set`s are not indexable...

Comment: Anyway, it sounds to me like you are trying to reinvent an [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) with the aim of creating some vector-space representation of your documents.

Comment: Ok. Each sample is a document which is a collection of words which are strings. I'm tokenizing the entire document and then converting each word to lower case and adding it to a set. Once all the documents are parsed and the set is created, I'm converting it to a list. Now the indices of each word is fixed with respect to this list (which I call pool). So again iterating over the words of the documents (which are tokenized), we can find the index of the word in the pool.

Comment: Yeah, you should just be using an sklearn `CountVectorizer` with the `binary=True` argument. If you want to see what I mean by "use a dict" you can check out exactly how it is done in sklearn by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L745). That is the crux of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you want to be using a [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) for this, with the `binary=True` argument, since you don't actually want counts. You this creates your encoding *and* outputs a sparse-matrix to boot!

However, if you are interested in the underlying problem with your approach, fundamentally the issue is that you are using *a sequence type*, a `list`, where the `.index` method is *a linear-time* operation. You are feeling the pain of this fact when you try to use your list. Here is a *sketch* of how you could do this way more efficiently, using only a dictionary:

```
In [15]: tokens = list('qwertydfgndjfkgnf')

In [16]: pool = {}

In [17]: for t in tokens:
    ...:     pool.setdefault(t, len(pool))
    ...:

In [18]: pool
Out[18]:
{'d': 6,
 'e': 2,
 'f': 7,
 'g': 8,
 'j': 10,
 'k': 11,
 'n': 9,
 'q': 0,
 'r': 3,
 't': 4,
 'w': 1,
 'y': 5}

In [19]: tokens.index('g') # ew, O(n) time complexity
Out[19]: 8

In [20]: pool['g'] # nice! O(1) time complexity
Out[20]: 8
```

This pool now contains an encoding from tokens to index. And accessing the index is a *constant time* operation here. This will *significantly* improve performance. And indeed, since we are just making a `dict` to begin with, and not converting from a `set` to a `list`, this will cut down on your constant factors by a lot.

Note, the above is essentially what the `sklearn` object is doing.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L745

Note, however, they use a `defaultdict`, which is optimized for this sort of thing, with the following delightful little approach:

```
In [24]: from collections import defaultdict

In [25]: pool = defaultdict()

In [26]: pool.default_factory = pool.__len__

In [27]: for t in tokens:
    ...:     pool[t]
    ...:

In [28]: pool
Out[28]:
defaultdict(<method-wrapper '__len__' of collections.defaultdict object at 0x1088aa9f8>,
            {'d': 6,
             'e': 2,
             'f': 7,
             'g': 8,
             'j': 10,
             'k': 11,
             'n': 9,
             'q': 0,
             'r': 3,
             't': 4,
             'w': 1,
             'y': 5})
```

The also build the sparse representation *as they loop over the documents*, so they actually only do one pass over the data set. So the sklearn object is about as optimized as you are going to get. The sklearn source code is actually pretty approachable, and it is worth checking out what they accomplish using just pure python without Cython extensions or anything.

Comment: Great. This was what I wanted to know. Now, I understand what was wrong with my approach. +1 to the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this type of Encoding using scikit-learn's [Count Vectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer). See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage) for an example usecase. Because you mention machine learning and are using Python, I assume you are familiar with sklearn in general.

However, since CountVectorizer is intended for text tokenizing, using it for your problem is a bit hacky.

For example, if you have your input data in this format:

```
samples = [['A', 'B', 'D'],
           ['A', 'C', 'E'],
           ['A', 'C', 'D']]
```

You should first transform the inner lists to strings:

```
samples_s = ["".join(l) for l in samples]
```

which gives

```
['ABD', 'ACE', 'ACD']
```

Now you can fit an instance of CountVectorizer. You just have to define what constitutes a token. Here I used a simple regex to define any single character (e.g. "A", "B" or "C") as a token. You can also provide a static vocabulary.

```
vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='.')
X = vec.fit_transform(samples_s)
```

Calling `X.toarray()` returns

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Using sklearn's implementation should be much faster than doing the encoding yourself.